# Which AIX command's output is this?

Tags: aix

```
 Disk          Path  P     Location   adapter    LUN SN       Type         Size   LSS     Vol  Rank  C/A   S   Connection  port RaidMode
-------       -----  -   -----------  ------   -----------  ------------   ----   ----    ---  ----- ----  -   ----------- ---- --------
vpath0        hdisk7     06-00-02[FC] fscsi2   35KJ1320504  IBM 2107-900 65.5GB     2      2   0002   0e   Y   R1-B4-H1-ZA  300 RAID5
vpath0       hdisk19     06-00-02[FC] fscsi2   35KJ1320504  IBM 2107-900 65.5GB     2      2   0002   0e   Y   R1-B7-H3-ZA  630 RAID5
```

What command produces this output on AIX?

Comment: Depending on your storage backend (IBM/NetApp/EMC), there may be some vendor provided tools that will produce similar output.

Answer (score 4):

It's `datapath query essmap`.  The vpaths are the give-away.  Original SDD (used via the `datapath` command) created vpaths, while the newer and better supported SDDPCM (used via the `pcmpath` command) uses hdisks only.

Answer (score 2):

The command is:

```
pcmpath query essmap
```

No AIX knowledge here, I've just googled the header of that command, [like so](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Disk++++++++++Path++P+++++Location+++adapter++++LUN+SN+++++++Type+++++++++Size+++LSS+++++Vol++Rank++C%2FA+++S+++Connection++port+RaidMode%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: It's actually not pcmpath query, it's datapath query, because vpaths are delivered by SDD (datapath), if it was hdisks it would be sddpcm (which is pcmpath).